# NameError while using eval() function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to call a module from another module by using the `eval()` function it is calling successfully but in console output i am getting error message like "NameError: name 'Login_CSA' is not defined"

I have written the code like this

In sample.py module

```
import ReferenceUnits

def calling():
    str='Login_CSA'
    eval(str)

calling()
```

In ReferenceUnits.py

```
import Login_CSA
```

and in Login_CSA.py I have written

```
def Hai():
    print "hello this is somesh"
    print 'hi welcome to Hai function'

Hai()
```

It is executing but finally getting error message like `"NameError: name 'Login_CSA' is not defined"`

Why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are trying to "include and evaluate a second script" like you would do in PHP. In Python, when you `import` a file, all the methods become available in your local script. So instead of `eval`ing the file you would just call the method from it.

```
import ReferenceUnits
import Login_CSA

def calling():
    Login_CSA.Hai()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    calling()
```

and change `Login_CSA.py` to

```
def Hai():
    print "hello this is somesh"
    print 'hi welcome to Hai function'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Hai()
```

the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block is important as it prevents imported scripts from executing code during `import` (you only very rarely want to execute code on import).

Comment: "*(you never want to execute code on import).*" - *never* is a bit harsh - as sometimes you do :)

Comment: Your idea of importing `Login_CSA` inside `ReferenceUnits` may need some testing, maybe the function `Hai()` is available via `ReferenceUnits.Login_CSA.Hai()`...

Comment: Okay... "very rarely" then :-D

Answer (score 1):

The function `eval()` executes valid python expressions such as:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> print eval('x+1')
2
```

In your case the `eval()` function looks for the variable `Login_CSA` which simply doesn't exist, So it returns `NameError: name 'Login_CSA' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

If you

- import `Login_CSA` in `ReferenceUnits.py`,
- import `ReferenceUnits` in `sample.py`,

you have to access

- `ReferenceUnits` by using `ReferenceUnits`,
- `Login_CSA` by using `ReferenceUnits.Login_CSA` and
- `Hai` by using `ReferenceUnits.Login_CSA.Hai`.

So you can do

```
def calling():
    str='ReferenceUnits.Login_CSA.hai'
    eval(str)() # the () is essential, as otherwise, nothing gets called.

calling()
```